# Connection works, iwconfig doesn't

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, ifconfig

I am trying to get information about my wlan0 connection from iwconfig. When I run iwconfig I get this:

```
wlan0     no wireless extensions.
```

When I run ifconfig I get

```
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:8c:b5:bb  
      inet addr:10.1.10.165  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: 2603:3021:1101:3800:f85:1f38:ffe1:8333/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2603:3021:1101:3800::9cd5/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::7406:9e58:85f7:9619/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7299987 (7.2 MB)  TX bytes:469380 (469.3 KB)
```

My connection has an IP address, and I'm connected to this machine over ssh, so I know the internet is working. If I run nmcli commands it appears to be normal. Why then does iwconfig not display information about this connection.

Answer (score 0):

It might be, because `iwconfig` uses the deprecated WEXT API and your kernel has no support for it enabled. Use the `iw` tool instead.

Btw, `ifconfig` is also deprecated for `iproute2` (`ip link`), but the underlying ioctl ABI that it uses is still around.